# distcp fails when copying from s3 to hdfs

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

Created a cluster (Spark Amazon EMR) and tried to run in command line.

**CLI:**

> hadoop distcp s3a://bucket/file1 /data

**Exception:**

```
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidAuxServiceException: The auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.instantiateExceptionImpl(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:171)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.instantiateException(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:182)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.deSerialize(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$Container.launch(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:162)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$EventProcessor.run(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:408)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the properties of yarn-site.xml in /etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml,

```
 <property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name> 
  <value>mapreduce_shuffle,spark_shuffle</value>
 </property>

 <property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.spark_shuffle.class</name> 
   <value>org.apache.spark.network.yarn.YarnShuffleService</value> 
 </property>

<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name> 
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
```

If mapreduce_shuffle is not there, please add the properties and restart the yarn services.

```
sudo stop hadoop-yarn-nodemanager
sudo start hadoop-yarn-nodemanager
```

I recommend to use **s3-distcp** utility because its already available in EMR cluster.

```
s3-dist-cp --src s3://my-tables/incoming/hourly_table --dest /data/hdfslocation/path
```

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/seven-tips-for-using-s3distcp-on-amazon-emr-to-move-data-efficiently-between-hdfs-and-amazon-s3/

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Used s2-distcp instead of distcp, it covers everything behind s3.